# Quick links don't get styled properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, quick-links

I am using the Quick Links Web Part in SPO. The links are set to be 'tiles'.
When editing, I get a grid of 9 links/tiles per row. But when I publish the page, it creates a row of 7 and a shorter row of 2 below for each of my "normal" 9-tile rows.

Previously the number of links/tiles per row changed only with resizing the browser's window, and even then all of the rows kept the same length.

Is there anything I could do to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This is due to responsive nature of quick links web part. No. of links per row will be adjusted according to the space available on section layout column. For example: No. of links per row will be different for one column, two columns, three columns, etc layouts. Also it will different on team site and communication site, as communication site don't have left navigation, it can have more links per row.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a test in my environment, the quick links web part works fine on my end.

[image]

If you add the Quick Links Web Part in other sites, will the same issue exist?

Comment: It seems like the issue depends on the browsers. It continues to be displayed incorrectly in Firefox, but works well in Chrome and other browsers I checked